# How to marge two arrays data and save one SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two array. I want merge and insert to the database using php. here i put some array data. but my array is very big one.

**Array1**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003211
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2235
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003458
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2495
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003211
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2235
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003587
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2624
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003614
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2651
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003682
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2721
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003685
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2724
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ALT_ID] => 2003777
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2814
            [CUSTOM_30] => JAN
            [TITLE] => Level 4
        )
)
```

**Array2**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [COURSE_ID] => 1
            [TITLE] => Programming Methodology      
            [SHORT_NAME] => ECSI402 
            [MODULE_STATUS] => Core
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [COURSE_ID] => 2
            [TITLE] => Communication and Learning Skills in Computer Science  (SE) 
            [SHORT_NAME] => ECSI400         
            [MODULE_STATUS] => Core
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [COURSE_ID] => 3
            [TITLE] => Computer Systems Fundamentals    
            [SHORT_NAME] => ECSI404   
            [MODULE_STATUS] => Core
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [COURSE_ID] => 4
            [TITLE] => Information and Data Modeling  (SE) 
            [SHORT_NAME] => EBSI401        
            [MODULE_STATUS] => Core
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [COURSE_ID] => 5
            [TITLE] => Software Development Principles          
            [SHORT_NAME] => ECSI406  
            [MODULE_STATUS] => Core
        )
)
```

**I want these two data submit to the one table. this is the SQL query for that.**

```
INSERT INTO MODULE_REG (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID, DATE_REGISTERED, REGISTERED, ACADEMIC_SESSION)
```

**My database table i want save like this. this is sample one. i have to submit these two arrays all data for like this.**

```
 +-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
|student id | course id| registered| data_registered| academic ses|
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
|  2235     |    1     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
|  2235     |    2     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
|  2235     |    3     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
|  2495     |    1     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
|  2495     |    2     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
|  2495     |    3     |     Y     |  2017.11.16    |  Level 4    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The general idea would be to setup a parametrized query, loop through the array and execute the query with the unique data.

Comment: what is the association of array 2 with array 1? How do you know which student belongs to which course

Comment: @RedBottle, please, can you check that table. I want save the data like that.

Comment: I want all student save to all courses

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){

$student_id[$i]=$array1[$i]['STUDENT_ID'];
$accademic_ses[$i]=$array1[$i]['ACADEMIC_SESSION'];
for($j=0;$j<count($array2);$j++){

$sql= "INSERT INTO MODULE_REG (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID, DATE_REGISTERED, REGISTERED, ACADEMIC_SESSION) VALUES (".$student_id[$i].",".$course_id[$j].",/*add your registered and data_registered here/*,".$accademic_ses[$i].")";

/*execute your sql here*/
}
}
```

I cannot see any values for registered and data_registered so I didnt add. You can add accordingly.

Comment: I added this code but not working. please can you help me.

Comment: can u edit your question with the changes you made with my answer? Its difficult to help without seeing your code and errors.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
$student_id[$i]=$result[$i]['STUDENT_ID'];
$acyear_id[$i]=$result[$i]['ACADEMIC_SESSION'];

for($j=0;$j<count($result1);$j++){
$date       = date("Y-m-d");
$sql= "INSERT INTO MODULE_REGISTRATION (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID,REGISTERED, DATE_REGISTERED, ACADEMIC_SESSION) " "VALUES (".$student_id[$i].",".$course_id[$j].",".'Y'.",".$date. ",".$acyear_id[$i].")";
DBQuery($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
}`

Comment: i wrote like this.

Comment: thank you for your answer i found the answer. it is similar to your one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. **`$result` is `array1`**..
**`$result1` is `array2`**

```
     foreach ($result as $value){

    $value[STUDENT_ID];
    $value[TITLE];
   foreach($result1 as $values){
    $values[COURSE_ID];

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $sql= "INSERT INTO MODULE_REGISTRATION (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID,REGISTERED, DATE_REGISTERED, ACADEMIC_SESSION) "
    . "VALUES ('".$value[STUDENT_ID]."','".$values[COURSE_ID]."', 'Y' ,'".$date. "','".$value[TITLE]."')";
    DBQuery($sql);

    }
}
```